# Python ARIMA out of sample prediction

Tags: python, forecasting, arima

I'm trying to make ARIMA out of sample predictions. Below is part of my code

```
n_periods = 8
(confint, fc) = con_fc
con_fc = arima_model_results.predict(n_periods=n_periods, return_conf_int=True)

index_of_fc = np.arange(len(df2_val), len(df2_val)+n_periods)
```

I'm getting error message:

```
      1 n_periods = 8
----> 2 (confint, fc) = con_fc
      3 con_fc = arima_model_results.predict(n_periods=n_periods, return_conf_int=True)
      4 
      5 index_of_fc = np.arange(len(df2_val), len(df2_val)+n_periods)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

tried different websites but didn't find an aswer

Comment: Do `len(con_fs)`. Is it 2?

Comment: len(con_fc) gives 45

Comment: If `len(con_fs)` returns 45, you need to see why. You are trying to unpack 45 values into two variables. You are probably working with Pandas or a Numpy array, yeah? Are you trying to unpack an array? What should confint and fc be?